# MySQL Count(*) issue when using UNION

Tags: mysql

I am currently having problems with using Count(*) in a UNION statement when there's multiple WHERE clauses.

Here is the MySQL syntax I'm trying to get to work:

```
    SELECT Count(*)
    FROM   (SELECT title,
                   taskstatus,
                   Extract(year FROM finished)  AS year,
                   Extract(month FROM finished) AS month
            FROM   todo_languages
            UNION ALL
            SELECT title,
                   taskstatus,
                   Extract(year FROM finished)  AS year,
                   Extract(month FROM finished) AS month
            FROM   todo_main
            UNION ALL
            SELECT title,
                   taskstatus,
                   Extract(year FROM finished)  AS year,
                   Extract(month FROM finished) AS month
            FROM   todo_addons) AS a
    WHERE  taskstatus = 1
           AND year = 2014
           AND month = 04
```

What have I tried myself before asking for help here?

First off, I tested to see if the just getting the count using the taskstatus worked like this:

```
    SELECT Count(*)
    FROM   (SELECT title,
                   taskstatus,
                   Extract(year FROM finished)  AS year,
                   Extract(month FROM finished) AS month
            FROM   todo_languages
            UNION ALL
            SELECT title,
                   taskstatus,
                   Extract(year FROM finished)  AS year,
                   Extract(month FROM finished) AS month
            FROM   todo_main
            UNION ALL
            SELECT title,
                   taskstatus,
                   Extract(year FROM finished)  AS year,
                   Extract(month FROM finished) AS month
            FROM   todo_addons) AS a
    WHERE  taskstatus = 1
```

The above worked fine and returned the current count of 1. Next, I tested to make sure getting the count by the month and year worked as so:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   (SELECT title,
               taskstatus,
               Extract(year FROM finished)  AS year,
               Extract(month FROM finished) AS month
        FROM   todo_languages
        UNION ALL
        SELECT title,
               taskstatus,
               Extract(year FROM finished)  AS year,
               Extract(month FROM finished) AS month
        FROM   todo_main
        UNION ALL
        SELECT title,
               taskstatus,
               Extract(year FROM finished)  AS year,
               Extract(month FROM finished) AS month
        FROM   todo_addons) AS a
WHERE  year = 2014
       AND month = 04
```

This also worked and returned the row count of 1, but the first query returns a row count of 0, which leads me here. Is there something I'm not seeing that I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain what exactly is your problem?

Comment: My issue is the first query, which is the one I want to use, returns a row count of 0.

Comment: does it have anything to do with table names? in the first query you have "todo_Languages" and in the second and third query you have "todo_Trackr_Languages"? and the same goes for other two tables...

Comment: No, I just forgot to modify them in the question, but I'll do that now. When I tested the table names were the same.

Comment: Please format your queries with line breaks, it’s hard to get what there about when one has to scroll a single line for several yards.

Comment: do you have any actual record in your tables which meets these three conditions(taskstatus = 1 AND year = 2014 AND month = 04)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you confused? You can have record `WHERE taskstatus = 1` also you can have record `WHERE year = 2014 AND month = 04` but no records where `WHERE taskstatus = 1 AND year = 2014 AND month = 04`.

Imagine:

```
taskstatus     year       month
1              2000       05
2              2004       04
```

Comment: Nvm, I seem to have modified the wrong task in phpMyAdmin. My own stupid mistake.

Comment: I updated my comment above, and accepted this answer because it made me double check the table.